# How do I add more visualizations into VLC?

Tags: vlc

Am using VLC 2.0.8 and I was wondering if its possible to add more visualizations to show when playing audio?

**EDIT**
VLC has two waves in its scope visualization. Is there a way I can remove one? Am looking for something like 'simple scope' in banshee media player or 'blur scope' in Audacious.

I tried the projectM visualizations but didn't like them; I just then deleted them.

Comment: You want the "how to" or a lists of "all of them"?

Comment: @Braiam I think both would be fine, priority a "how to".

Answer (score 1):

you can use ProjectM visualizations. you can download them from

http://projectm.sourceforge.net/

after downloading them extract them with

```
tar -xvf <filename.tar>
```

Then open INSTALL file  with favorite text editor. they will have the installation instructions